# Постановка запятых и точка после кавычек

Tags: пунктуация

В каких местах нужны запятые:

1. "...справа от него(,) поодаль(,) небольшой прудик".
2. "Они были насквозь мокрые(,) - дождь лил как из ведра(,) - но счастливые".
3. "Мне точно конец"(.) - нужно ли ставить точку после кавычек? (это мысль, оформленная отдельным предложением, и далее не следуют слова типа "подумал я").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...справа от него, поодаль, небольшой прудик". Это уточнение (сужение значения, = чуть в стороне).

"Они были насквозь мокрые - дождь лил как из ведра, - но счастливые". Это вставная конструкция, отнесенная к первой части предложения, поэтому два тире, но одна запятая.

"Мне точно конец". Отдельное предложение заканчивается точкой.

Comment: Насколько я помню, точка ставится после закрывающих кавычек

Answer (score 0):

Постановка запятых и точка после кавычек

Отвечаю на вопрос в его исходном состоянии. После правки понять, о чем спрашивают уже стало трудно.

> В каких местах нужны запятые:
>   ~1. "...справа от него() поодаль() небольшой прудик."
>   ~2. "Они были насквозь мокрые() - дождь лил как из ведра() - но счастливые."
>   ~3. "«Мне точно конец»()" - нужно ли ставить точку после кавычек? (это мысль, оформленная отдельным предложением, и далее не следуют слова типа: "подумал я").

~1. Корректно: *"...справа от него, поодаль, небольшой прудик"*. Точка перед закрывающими кавычками не ставится. Вместо второй запятой возможно (и даже предпочтительно) тире.

~2. Корректно: *"Они были насквозь мокрые - дождь лил как из ведра, - но счастливые"*. Точка перед закрывающими кавычками не ставится. В отношении сочетания знаков при тире парном тире вопрос весьма спорный. Полагаю, здесь при первом тире запятая не нужна, поскольку она ничем не мотивирована, кроме самого тире, а вторая нужна, поскольку здесь нет причин для его "поглощения", она отвечает не за обособление конструкции и без того обособленной с помощью парного тире, а ставится перед противительным союзом. ("но").  Но, повторяю, этот вопрос весьма дискуссионный. тут неоднократно обсуждался.

~3. После кавычек нужна точка. Внутри кавычек, после слова конец никаких знаков не требуется (в этой позиции возможны только знакт, относящиеся к закавыченной фразе: вопросительный и восклицательный, многоточие - и их сочетания.